# Event button as a module or as user program?

Tags: linux, module, embedded, daemon

I am programming a push button to start the software in a linux based board.
A push button on Linux based embedded board. GPIO didn't work with that Linux kernel, so instead, I used the event interface. The button is basically listening for button press to activate all the hardware and stops the hardware when it's pressed twice. I would like to know whether write as a kernel module or as a user program? Or as a deamon?

Comment: can you elaborate what a start button program is? if you have the option of writing it as a module.. what is it a module of?

Comment: @user1055604 from the linux tag, obviously a loadable kernel module

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible to do it in user space (i.e. daemon) you should do it there.

In this case both might be required. You'll need to access the button somehow, which will depend on what the hardware looks like. Then you'll need to respond to an event and perform an action based on that.

Following the 'policy does not belong in the kernel' mantra, this means that while you can (and probably need to) handle the button itself from the kernel you need to do the starting the application part from user space. The kernel should not be in the business of starting new user space processes. Instead it should pass the even to user space, through a netlink socket for example. You then need a user space daemon which listens on the netlink socket and starts the application in response to certain events.

Comment: Yes.  Often the module is already available - a GPIO driver exposing sysfs nodes.  The userspace daemon (or even desired program) can configure and then do a blocking read on a level-sensitive one.  There it will sit, process suspended, until the input changes.

Comment: The GPIO can't be exported to the user-land. I used event interface instead. I am not sure it is related to GPIO and what mechanism lies behind, so I just use pthread currently. What's the benefits doing the other way.

Comment: Actually yes, GPIOs **can** be exported to userspace. There's a sysfs interface for them. Even if that didn't exist you could always create your own interface using `ioctl()`s or netlink. I have no idea why you think pthread would be relevant in this discussion. The fundamental point remains: handling the hardware specific bits of the GPIO should be done in the kernel, starting applications should be handled by user space. The two should communicate using standard interfaces like (not an exchaustive list, but if you try to add a syscall I shall be very upset) `ioctl()`s or netlink sockets.

Comment: Sorry, I am newbie. "the board registers a platform device "gpio-keys" for these buttons. Older kernels used the gpio sysfs interface for these buttons." I don't know if this event interface has anything to do with GPIO. From my own experiment, GPIO pins can be exported but not written to." The fundamental point remains: handling the hardware specific bits of the GPIO should be done in the kernel, starting applications should be handled by user space." I would like to dig into that. Do you show any examples?